# Customize proof-general's dark theme for Isabelle

Tags: emacs, themes, syntax-highlighting, isabelle, proof-general

I'm a novice in both [Isabelle](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/) and [Proof General](http://proofgeneral.inf.ed.ac.uk/).

I am trying to set a dark theme in Proof General to use with Isabelle, but no matter what theme I choose (e.g. `tango-dark`, `ample`, `monokai`, etc.), the untouched inner syntax is highlighted in a very hard to read green. I looked into customizing the theme but haven't figured out where to customize it. Below is a screenshot in `tango-dark`.

[image: Isabelle in Proof General with tango-dark theme]

Is there an existing nice dark theme that works well with Isabelle, or how do I customize the highlighting of Isabelle's inner syntax in Proof General?

Comment: Put your cursor on the green text in question and do `C-u C-x =`. You should get a new window with quite a lot of content, one piece of which is its `face`. That's the face you'll need to customize.

Comment: @Chris works! You're my hero. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

As a novice of Isabelle you should ignore Proof General altogether.  It was important 10-12 years ago, but turned into genuine legacy about 3 years ago, when the first production-ready releases of Isabelle/jEdit (the Prover IDE) appeared.

Note that Isabelle2014 is actually the last Isabelle release, where Proof General can in principle still be used.  Support for it has already been removed from the code-base, and there will be no trace of it left in the coming Isabelle2015 release (to appear in Spring 2015).

It means, users insisting in some Emacs-based Isabelle interface cannot get past the state of late summer 2014, unless they implement their own based on Isabelle/PIDE infrastructure.

(I am posting this here with a genuine danger of getting downgraded by adherents of Emacs.  I used to be one myself many years ago, but that is long past.)

Comment: Well thanks makarius :). Emacs is my favorite editor, that's why I look for Proof General. It's actually great that you used to be an Emacs person too, because I can ask you for experience in how to transition from Emacs to say jEdit for Isabelle without losing the benefits (e.g. being keyboard centric, hackability, etc.)

Comment: Wile supporting Emacs indeed is not the task of a languages developer, blocking Emacs by hard-coding jEdit into the core-procedure looks like a strategic error.

Comment: It is a bit dangerous to use this tiny marginal note system for such a discussion.  Please read my papers about Isabelle/PIDE and Isabelle/jEdit, to understand the concepts behind all this.  Emacs is not "blocked" in any way, there is just nobody who made a PIDE implementation for it (and I am not going to do anything myself).

Comment: More notes to Phil: from 1991 to 2006 I was using Emacs routinely (that makes 15 years); then I switched to jEdit, and had to spend 15 days to unlearn Emacs idiosyncrazies and learn jEdit.  Today I am much faster with jEdit as texteditor than I ever was with Emacs.  Note that Isabelle/jEdit is not just "jEdit" as texteditor: it is a Prover IDE (PIDE) implementation for jEdit.  There are others, like Isabelle/Eclipse for PIDE.